# positioning elements center in the page and inline

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this with the given code structure:

[image]

And here is the structure:

```css
.btnExitScreen {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10002;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #006aff;
    padding: 0.5vw 3.9vw;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    top: 40vw;
    width: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

#exitBtn {
    margin-left: 260px;
}

#pauseContainer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #22282F;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10001;
}

.fullscreenMessage {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10002;
  color: #E5F0FF;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="pauseScreenContainer"> 
  <button id="continueBtn" class="btnExitScreen">Continue</button> 
  <button id="exitBtn" class="btnExitScreen">Exit</button>  
  <div id="pauseContainer"></div> 
  <div class="fullscreenMessage">This is a centered message!</div> 
</div>
```

I also don't want any distortion (like changing in position) when resizing the page.

So far I'm unable to find a proper solution. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you change the structure of the html? Like add an additional div around the buttons?

Comment: YES...of course....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.pauseScreenContainer {
position: relative;
    background-color: #22282F;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 10001;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
#pauseContainer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%,50%)!important;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
}

.btnExitScreen {
    z-index: 10002;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #006aff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

#exitBtn {
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.fullscreenMessage {
  z-index: 10002;
  color: #E5F0FF;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pauseScreenContainer">  
  <div id="pauseContainer">
  <div class="fullscreenMessage">This is a centered message!</div> 
  <button id="continueBtn" class="btnExitScreen">Continue</button> 
  <button id="exitBtn" class="btnExitScreen">Exit</button> 
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

The code will be like that way.I used position and transform css.

Comment: Please add also some explanation of why this code answer the question, it would help someone